# How To Put Small Pictures in front of Combo box items?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need your Some time to help me, I am creating a project in which I need to set little pictures like 32X32 or 16X16 pixels, in front of combo box items.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link may help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10670/Image-ComboBox-Control

edit, to do that in VB, set your combobox DrawMode property to OwnerDraw, then:

```
protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs)
    
    e.DrawBackground()
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    Dim item As New ComboBoxIconItem
    Dim imageSize As New Size
    imageSize = ListaImg1.ImageSize
    Dim bounds As New Rectangle
    bounds = e.Bounds
    Try
        item = Me.Items(e.Index)
        If (item.ImageIndex <> -1) Then
            Me.ImageList.Draw(e.Graphics, bounds.Left, _
                bounds.Top, item.ImageIndex)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, e.Font, _
                New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), bounds.Left + _
                imageSize.Width, bounds.Top)
        Else
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, e.Font, _
                New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), bounds.Left, _
                bounds.Top)
        End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        If (e.Index <> -1) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Items(e.Index).ToString(), e.Font, _
                New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), bounds.Left, bounds.Top)
        Else
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, e.Font, _
                New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), bounds.Left, bounds.Top)
        End If
    End Try
    MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)
End Sub
```

Comment: i thing it is not vb 2008 language, its C or C++, Not helpful but thanks for quick response.

Comment: it's C#, its gives you the idea, and it's easy to convert to VB.

Comment: ownerdraw is a property, don't set your combo name as ownerdraw!!